# How to fix the error log not appearing at once?

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

I've been getting weird errors from before.

When I run the app with the wrong code,
The error log does not occur at once.

I have to run it `twice` to get the error log.

The first time I run it, the app just turns off. After that, when I run the app again, an error occurrence dialog is displayed and the app is terminated.

What's wrong with this?

I am experiencing discomfort in development because of this.

`current version  Android Studio 4.1.2`

`compileSdkVersion 29`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is not with your log the main issue is that you need to run your app twice to get the desired output.

Go to `Run -> Edit configurations... -> disable check box (Allow parallel run)*`

After that run the app and see the log, it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to find the error is enabling this option on Android Studio which will pause the IDE and show the error.

[image]